SwiftUI List Error 'Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'
This is my code:
struct ContentView: View {

    // an array of oceans
    private var oceans = [
        Ocean(name: "Pacific"),
        Ocean(name: "Atlantic"),
        Ocean(name: "Indian"),
        Ocean(name: "Southern"),
        Ocean(name: "Arctic")
    ]
    
    // an array of numbers
    private var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    var body: some View {
           
        VStack{
            
            List(oceans) { ocean in
                Text("\(ocean.name)")
            }
            
            List(nums) { num in // error appears here
                
            }
            
      }//VStack
}

I tried to call
List(nums) { num in }

But it won't let me and gave me the error

Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'Range

Do you know why it works with oceans but not nums?

Int doesn’t conform to Identifiable so you need to explain what the unique id is like List(nums, id: \.self) { num in } if all numbers are unique in the array.

I called it again like this List(nums, id: \.self) { num in                 Text("\(num)")             }, and the numbers showed up. Thank you!
